# Angular 2 Promise Not Returning Object

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a simple service that returns a promise. However, it only triggers the then() if it is a primitive. I cannot figure this out for the life of me. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I realize it is probably something simple, but I have looked at many examples and just can't figure out why it isn't returning my object from my service.

```
//CreateLayer inside IncidentLayer class
public CreateLayer(): Promise<any>{         
   return this.incidentService.getIncidents().toPromise().then((incs) => {
        var gfx = this.createGraphics(incs);//not an async function
        var lyr = new this._mapDependencies.FeatureLayer({
            source: gfx              
        });

        //return lyr;WILL NOT TRIGGER
        return "test";//WORKS
    }); 

}
 ......
  this.incidentLayer.CreateLayer().then((lyr)=>{
          console.log(lyr);//only triggers if lyr is a primitive
        });
```

**EDIT:**

It seems it is related to the type. If I use Point, it works fine.

```
var lyr = new this._mapDependencies.Point();
return lyr;//works
```

I get no error in the console or after adding a catch(), so I am not sure how to even go about debugging it.

_mapDependencies is created through the following esri angular loader library.

```
  return this.esriLoader.load({  
        url: 'https://js.arcgis.com/4.6/' 
    }).then(() => {
        return this.esriLoader.loadModules([
            'esri/Map', 'esri/views/MapView', 'esri/layers/GraphicsLayer', 'esri/layers/FeatureLayer', "esri/tasks/Geoprocessor",
            "esri/tasks/support/FeatureSet", "esri/Graphic","esri/geometry/Point"
        ]).then(([
            Map, MapView, GraphicsLayer, FeatureLayer, Geoprocessor, FeatureSet, Graphic,PointObj
        ]) => {

       //this is where the object comes from that allows me to say 
       //new this._mapDependencies.FeatureLayer() or Point() etc
       //once again, new Point() works, but FeatureLayer() does not, 
       //even though both objects are filled

            return {
                Geoprocessor: Geoprocessor,                  
                Graphic: Graphic,
                GraphicsLayer: GraphicsLayer,
                FeatureLayer: FeatureLayer,
                FeatureSet: FeatureSet,
                Point:PointObj
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: First off, remove the return type `Promise<any>` is compatible with all promises so it will suppress an error if you forget to `return`. Let the type inference guide you.

Comment: You don't have `.catch`, for starters (although you likely should get errors from zone in console). It looks improbable that `return lyr` alone will cause an error, because there's nothing wrong with `lyr` variable, it's defined and there's no difference for next `then` which one will be logged. Consider providing http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and a way to replicate the problem, because currently it looks that you have something behind the scenes, e.g. you forgot to restart build process, have older file cached, etc.

Comment: It seems the issue lies in the creation of new this._mapDependencies.FeatureLayer(); This esri object won't trigger the resolve() for some reason. Passing a normal object works fine( var tmp={test:1}. I thought I was doing something wrong with the promises. Still not sure why it doesn't resolve the object, regardless of whatever type it is.

Answer (score 0):

Your CreateLayer() function does not return a promise! You can't resolve the promise and also return it as a promise. It will be easier to do with [RxJs](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS) obserables, but a solution with promises should be look like :

```
public CreateLayer(): Promise<any>{         
   return new Promise(resolve=>{
   this.incidentService.getIncidents().toPromise().then((incs) => {
        var gfx = this.createGraphics(incs);//not an async function
        var lyr = new this._mapDependencies.FeatureLayer({
            source: gfx              
        });    
        resolve(lyr);
       })
    }); 
}
```

I'm wrapping your getIncidents() with another promise and this is the promise that is returning to anyone who will call this function. When it will be resolved, the calling function .then() callback will be

You should read a little bit more about how promises work [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: If you look at my edit, you'll see I made some progress. Your code also fails to trigger then then() if I use this._mapDependencies.FeatureLayer(), but if I use this._mapDependencies.Point(), or any other esri type in that object, it works fine. What's weird is the FeatureLayer object has many initialized properties and looks fine, so I am not sure at all why it fails to return.

Comment: What is _mapDependencies? is it an instance of some kind of third party library ? (Google maps?)

Comment: I'm no familiar with this library, But from https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-FeatureLayer.html it looks like you don't initialize FeatureLayer as it should. You should pass it a url and some other options...  What is gfx in your code?

Comment: You can initialize it using an array of graphics objects as well(which is what I was doing). I can get this to work IF I use subscriber() and access a class member this.MapFeatureLayer, so I know the initialization of the feature layer is working, it just isn't returning from a promise(which is driving me insane at this point).